# How to change a column values from dataframe comparing value from another dataframe only if the new value is not empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this info let call it df1:

```
Patient Id      Email
5628        mapy@gmail.com
17433       ssdx@gmail.com
8614
15336       cris@yahoo.es
17604       avasallo@yahoo.com
8635        carolinavi@gmail.com
15424
15393       TAM20@YAHOO.COM
```

also have df2 which is bigger but for sure it have the patient id but It may have a different email or even dont have it at all. so what I want to do is replace the email in df1 with the one in df2 where the patient ids match and if the df2 email is not empty.

so I have tried with this:

```
df1['Email'] = df1['Patient Id'].map(df2.set_index('patient_id')['email_address'])
```

it locate correctly the match of the patient ids and replace the email but it replace it even when df2 email is empty ending up like this:

```
Patient Id      Email                   email nuevo
5628        mapy@gmail.com          mapy@gmail.com
17433       ssdx@gmail.com          ssdx002gmail.com
8614        
15336       cris@yahoo.es       
17604       avasallo@yahoo.com      avasallo@yahoo.com
8635        carolinavi@gmail.com    carolinavictoria.md@gmail.com
15424       
15393       TAM20@YAHOO.COM         TACM2010@YAHOO.COM
```

as you can see, it the email ssdx@gmail.com and TAM20@YAHOO.com but also overwrite cris@yahoo.es with an empty cell that's what i want to avoid.

any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: use `replace` instead of `map`.

Comment: but if the ids aren't in the same order will replace() look for it?

Comment: Yes........................................

Comment: I did it but is doing the same, still replacing df1 emails with df2 empty email cells

Comment: chain that with a `fillna(df1.Email)`.

Comment: I actually don't have Nan values I have empty strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 = df2.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df2 = df2.set_index("patient_id")['email_address'].fillna(df1.set_index('Patient Id')['Email']).reset_index()
df1['Email'] = df1['Patient Id'].map(df2.set_index('patient_id')['email_address'])
```

The first line replaces empty strings with NaN. The second line fills the Nan values in df2 with values from df1. The last line is the same as the line you had.